# Two Primary keys of different tables as foreign keys to another table

Tags: c#, .net, sql, winforms

I have a winForms application with DataGridView, 3 tables and some queries.

Lets say I have Tables , A,B,C.
In table A I have an auto increment primary Key and also in table B.
Tables A and B are both strangers.

Table C is a Join Table that have 2 columns:

1) A primary Key

2) B primary Key

Now, in the form I have a button and it's just programmatically inserts values for table A and B. 
What I'm trying to do is to  insert the primary keys of tables A and B to the right columns in table C.
is it possible to do it programmatically?

Comment: might be a good idea to explain primary key of table C

Comment: Table C just connects between table A and table B by 
those primary keys..

Answer (score 1):

if you using sql server you can run in your buttonclick code this:

```
declare @aid int, @bid int 
insert A(col1) values(val1) 
set @aid = scope_identity()

insert B(col1) values(val1) 
set @bid = scope_identity()

insert C(aid, bid) values(@aid, @bid)
```